# Retrieve BLOB .bin image to be viewed

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have two files;

image.php

```
<?php
// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();


$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());
//Your code to call database for image id (from _GET['id']), for instance:
$image_id = $_GET['pid'];
$data = mysql_query("Select img where pid = $image_id");

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
  $image=$data['img'];
  header("content-type: image/png");
  echo $image;
}
?>
```

and ay.html to view the image;

```
<img src="image.php?pid=IMAGE_ID" />
```

After many examples I tried, and every thread on this site and elsewhere, I'm still getting this error;

```
The image"http....../image.php?pid=IMAGE_ID" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

Any help would be appreciated.
By the way the MySql variable is a LONGBLOB called img
I wonder why there isn't a simple IMG type for MySQL variable!

Comment: Storing images in the database is generally/most of the times wrong. Databases should keep references to the location of the image stored in the filesystem. That's why there's no IMG type in most RDBMS.

Comment: Unfortunately I've realized that but how can I view that blob on an html page?

Answer (score 0):

You should post how you stored the image to see exactly what it's wrong with your code but as the error says the image has some kind of error hence it was not stored correctly to database.

Generally the steps to go from an image to binary data and reverse are as below:

Image to binary conversion:

```
<? php

$image_data=file_get_contents('test.jpg');

$encoded_image=base64_encode($image_data);

echo $encoded_image;

?>
```

Binary to image conversion:

```
<?php

$image_data = file_get_contents('test.jpg');

$encoded_image = base64_encode($image_data);

$decoded_image = base64_decode($encoded_image);

echo $decoded_image;

?>
```

What you're missing altogether is the base_64 encode to prevent symbols from being incorrectly ttransformed.

Answer (score -1):

/*In your html page...*/
/*    */

Comment: /*In your html page...*/
/*    <img src="image.php?pid=IMAGE_ID" />*/

Comment: <?php

//Here your connection configuration. Your table is called products
 
 $image_id = $_GET['pid'];
 
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE IMAGE_ID='$image_id'") ;

 $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  
 $image=base64_encode($data['img']);
  
 echo "data:image/png;base64,".$image;

?>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).